# Why is this texture displaying all black?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, textures

Here is the function where I am calling all of my draw operations. I also compile the shaders inline in the function. It displays the quad correctly when I just use colors for each vertex but textures don't want to work at all.

Here is the code:

```
void doGL2() {

    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    const GLchar* vertShader[] = { R"glsl(
            #version 330 core
            layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
            layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
            layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexPos;

            out vec3 col;
            out vec2 texturePos;

            void main()
            {
                gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
                col = aColor;
                texturePos = aTexPos;
            }
        )glsl" };



    const GLchar* fragShader[] = { R"glsl(
            #version 330 core
            out vec4 FragColor;

            in vec3 col;
            in vec2 texturePos;
            
            uniform sampler2D t;
            
            uniform vec2 iResolution;
            
            
            void main()
            {
                vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution;
                //FragColor = vec4(iResolution, 1., 1.);
                FragColor = mix(vec4(col, 1.0f), texture(t, gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(1200., 675.)), 1.);
            }
        )glsl" };



    vShader2 = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fShader2 = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);



    glShaderSource(vShader2, 1, vertShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vShader2);

    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[1024];
    glGetShaderiv(vShader2, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vShader2, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error("\noh no vert\n");
    }




    glShaderSource(fShader2, 1, fragShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fShader2);

    glGetShaderiv(fShader2, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fShader2, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error("\noh no frag\n");
    }




    shaderProgram2 = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(shaderProgram2, vShader2);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram2, fShader2);

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram2);

    GLfloat screen[2] = { 1200.0f, 675.0f };
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram2);

    glUniform2fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "iResolution"), 2, screen);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "t"), 10);

    //not sure if I should do this on cleanup or now
    glDeleteShader(vShader2);
    glDeleteShader(fShader2);


    
    //lets make a temporary test texture
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("tex2.jpg", &width, &height, &channels, 0);


    GLuint tempT = 1;

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE10);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glGenTextures(1, &tempT);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tempT);
    // set texture options
    
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    
    //glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free(data);
    
    
    

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // positions         // colors          // texture positions
         0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,         // bottom left
         1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,         // bottom right
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f          // top right
         ,
         0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,         // bottom left
         0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,         // top left
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f          // top right
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO2);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO2);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO2);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //positions
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //colors
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    //texture positions
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    

    float initTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    float prevTime = initTime;
    float dt = 0.0f;
    while (prevTime - initTime < 1000.0f) {
        

        dt = (glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - prevTime) / 1000.0f;
        prevTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

        glClearColor(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        
        glBindVertexArray(VAO2);
        
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tempT);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        
        SwapBuffers(GetDC(w));
        glFlush();
    }

}
```

For some reason, when I instead put the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` it displays the texture.

Edit:
I am making a further edit, as the content of my original question did not properly address the problem. It seems that I am unable to Bind any texture to any texture other than `GL_TEXTURE0`. I have seen other forums with this problem but the answers in those problems all address other issues that are not present here. As you can see I am trying to bind this texture to `GL_TEXTURE10`, however the output is all black. When I bind to `GL_TEXTURE0` however, the texture shows up fine. I have changed the code to reflect Rabbid's answer as those were indeed errors but not errors that affected this problem; the code is up to date reflecting the current problem.

Also, I printed `tempT` and it always returns as 1, meaning it is binding to `GL_TEXTURE0` every time despite what I call in `glActiveTexture()`.

Comment: There is no other problem with your code, I tested it. What is your system? Is this the original code? In what environment are you running the code?

Comment: *"Also, I printed tempT and it always returns as 1, meaning it is binding to GL_TEXTURE0 every time despite what I call in glActiveTexture()."* - The texture unit has nothing to do with the texture object ID. `tempT` does not indicate the texture unit! You have to set the texture unit before you bind the texture (before `glBindTexture`) but it has no effect to. `glGenTextures`.

Comment: I've added some suggestions to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not generating [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (with [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)) it is important to set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`. Since the default filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, the texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete" if you do not change the minimize function to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`.

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

In addition, the size of the image (`with`, `height`) must be specified instead of (1, 1):

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

---

It is not guaranteed that `stbi_load` generates a texture with 4 color channels. Force the `stbi_load` to generate an image with 4 color channels, by explicitly pass 4 to the last parameter:

<s>`unsigned char* data = stbi_load("tex2.jpg", &width, &height, &channels, 0);`</s>

```cpp
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("tex2.jpg", &width, &height, &channels, 4);
```

---

If you use a shader program, you don't need to enable texturing. Whether the texture is used or not is decided in the shader program. `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` is legacy OpenGL, remove it.

---

Aside from your code working fine, I tested it. However, the number of texture units is limited. Make sure you use a texture unit within range of your system. You can ger the number of texture units with [`GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml). e.g.:

```cpp
int max_units;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &max_units);
std::cout << "GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS " << max_units << std::endl;
```

---

> Also, I printed `tempT` and it always returns as 1, meaning it is binding to GL_TEXTURE0 every time despite what I call in `glActiveTexture()`.

The texture unit has nothing to do with the texture object ID. The value of `tempT` does not inidcate the texture unit in which the texture will be bouned. You must set the texture unit before binding the texture with `glBindTexture`, but it has no effect on `glGenTextures`. You can bind the texture to multiple texture units, or to different texture units at different times. The texture unit is the binding point between the texture object and the texture sampler uniform.
If you want to use a texture in a shader program, you need to make sure that the texture is bound to a texture unit and that unit is set to texture sampler uniform.

I suggest setting the texture unit before binding the texture and using it to draw the object:

```cpp
GLint t_location = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "t")
```

```cpp
glUseProgram(shaderProgram2);
glUniform1i(t_location, 10);
```

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE10);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tempT);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: @BradenYonano I've added some new suggestions to the answer.

Comment: So if the texture id, in this case `tempT`, is not the texture unit, then I should not be passing the texture id to the uniform sampler in the shader then correct? If this is true then how do I associate a unit with a texture id, like if I had 100 textures? My code works with these changes but only because I have 1 texture., I'm just wondering  what I would pass to the uniform if I can't pass the texture id.

Comment: @BradenYonano *"how do I associate a unit with a texture id, like if I had 100 textures"* - You can't use 100 different textures in one shader at the same time. (The GPU cannot cache all of these textures at once and process them with good performance). You have to use [`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)) or a texture atlas.

Comment: So I've got my code to work with the 128 textures I'm using (I'm rendering text) but it is quite slow as there are increasingly more characters. I believe this question has been answered in full though. Thank you for all of your insight!